# How do I  add a Ubuntu countdown widget into a forum?

Tags: widgets

I want to add this Ubuntu countdown widget:

http://corbindavenport.com/ubuntu/

into a forum, (in this case: http://www.fxp.co.il/forumdisplay.php?f=940)

how can i do that?

when I just copy-paste, it's only showing the code...

Comment: Not possible as forums don't allow iframe / display html pages.

Comment: On [aditiapratama.com](http://www.aditiapratama.com/2011/09/ubuntu-countdown-banner-unofficial.html) you have BBCcode for forum. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
- vB Code tag: iframe
- vB Code replacement: <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="{param}"><a href="{param}" target="_blank">{param}</a></iframe>
- vB Code example: [iframe]index.php?action=home[/iframe]
- Use option: no
```

[source](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/18640-iframe-in-bbcode)